# Changing the fontsize of the top x-axis in MatPlotLib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

For some reason, I want to plot the xtick label on the top axis. But the fontsize parameters can't be changed in the code below.  I plotted two subplots for reference.

```
f =plt.figure(figsize = (12,6))
ax1 = plt.subplot(211)


ax1.plot(np.arange(0,10,1),np.arange(0,10,1))

ax1.xaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
ax1.yaxis.set_ticks_position('both')

ax1.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', labeltop ='on',labelbottom = 'off')     
for tick in ax1.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
    tick.label.set_fontsize(24)


ax2 = plt.subplot(212)

ax2.plot(np.arange(0,10,1),np.arange(0,10,1))

ax2.xaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
ax2.yaxis.set_ticks_position('both')

ax2.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', labeltop ='off',labelbottom = 'on')     
for tick in ax2.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
    tick.label.set_fontsize(24)
```

[image]

Therefore, how to change the fontsize of the lable of x top axis?

Any advices would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that iterating through the labels with `ax1.xaxis.get_major_ticks()` only gives you a reference to the bottom labels. To set the font size for both the top and bottom labels, `set_tick_params` worked for me.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f =plt.figure(figsize = (12,6))
ax1 = plt.subplot(211)

ax1.plot(np.arange(0,10,1),np.arange(0,10,1))

ax1.xaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
ax1.yaxis.set_ticks_position('both')

ax1.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', labeltop ='on',labelbottom = 'off')
ax1.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=24)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the keyword argument `labelsize` instead of iterating over the ticks.

```
f = plt.figure(figsize = (12, 6))

ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
ax1.plot(np.arange(0, 10, 1),np.arange(0, 10, 1))

ax1.xaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
ax1.yaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', which='both',    
                labeltop='on', labelbottom='off', labelsize=27)


ax2 = plt.subplot(212)
ax2.plot(np.arange(0, 10, 1), np.arange(0, 10, 1))

ax2.xaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
ax2.yaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
ax2.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', 
                labeltop='off', labelbottom='on', labelsize=14)
```